# using tor broswer same time as brave with tor

Tags: browsers, brave

today i was thinking of situation: say i start tor browser and i browse internet with it. and later i start brave browser's window with tor. lets say i use both for different websites but simultaneously.

do they both use same port on localhost? does that mean it somehow connects brave surfing with tor browser surfing? or does brave use different port to set up tor network access. or perhaps if 9150 is already in use by one of the browsers, second browser gonna use different port?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Brave Browser and Tor Browser do not use the same port for the Tor Network.

- The Tor Browser uses port 9150.
- The Brave Browser Stable Release uses port 9250
- The Brave Browser Beta Release uses port 9260
- The Brave Browser Nightly Builds uses port 9270
- The Brave Browser Development builds use ports 9280 or 9290.

So the Tor Browser and Brave Browser connections do not interfere. I hope this answers your questions.

Source: https://community.brave.com/t/change-port-from-9050/27530/4